# How to apply tilt image animation repeatedly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

[image]

I have created a snippet. I want to tilt that image to both side repeatedly to both side.

```css
.demo{
  text-align:center;
  }
.demo img{
width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <img src="http://20dollarlogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Logo_TV_2015.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Comment: are you talking about an animation here

Comment: Yes i want to animate it...

Comment: Check the below snippet

Answer (score 1):

Check if this meets your requirement.

```js
var repeater;
doWork();
function doWork() { 
 repeater = setTimeout(doWork, 1000);
 if( $('.demo .test').hasClass( "flip" )){
   $('.demo .test').removeClass('flip');  
 }
 else{
    $('.demo .test').addClass('flip');  
 }
}
```

```css
.demo{
  text-align:center;
  }
.demo img{
width:50%;
  }

.flip {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <img class='test' src="http://20dollarlogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Logo_TV_2015.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with the `transform: rotate();` to give you the tilt effect. This in conjucture with CSS animation should give you what you are looking for.

Best part about this solution is that its purely CSS power.

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/XNVXEa)

```
.demo img{
  width:50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation-name: tilt;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes tilt {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20% { transform: rotate(7deg); }
  40% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  80% { transform: rotate(-7deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.